# Toggle WIFI from a background service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I need to make my service toggle Wifi on button press. I found this code to be a working solution

```java
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());
```

plus adding the appropriate permissions

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

However running that code from a background service causes the service to freeze! an abnormal behavior without any catched exceptions.

My best solution was to send an Intent from the service to an empty activity to start the Wifi from there (and it works!) but why starting it directly from the service is not working?

Comment: Service is running in main thread and it is good for long time operation which has no interaction with UI, and anything which freeze the UI should be done in background. Maybe it is better to send a broadcast from Service and your Broadcast receiver handle the code.

Comment: actually it doesn't matter as `setWifiEnabled` will not work anymore ...

Comment: @Ali thank you. I tested that on an `AsyncTask` and it worked great. Please post your comment as an answer to approve it.

Comment: @Selvin I'm aware of API 29 changes, however there are plenty (almost 99%) of android users how can still benefit from this method.
EDIT: 100% users till this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service is running in main thread and it is good for long time operation which has no interaction with UI, and anything which freeze the UI should be done in background. It could be better to send a broadcast from Service and your Broadcast receiver handle the code. As a sample you can look at : [Service](https://bitbucket.org/ali-rezaei/stopwatch/src/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/stopwatch/StopWatchService.java) and [Broadcast receiver](https://bitbucket.org/ali-rezaei/stopwatch/src/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/stopwatch/StopWatchActivity.java) where you can add :

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled());
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(STR_RECEIVER));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

And send broadcast from Service :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(STR_RECEIVER);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```